# Find the most recent date, and name of person who performed each task

Tags: indexing

I have looked all over for a solution for this with no luck. I think I'm making it more complicated then it needs to be. But here it is. I have a log of tasks that were performed on a given date by various people. I need a formula to tell me the most recent date each task was performed, and who it was performed by. Can anyone help me figure this out?

I've tried a combination of Index/Match, and max functions with no success.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alan: please include a minimal example of the input and the *desired output*. Also, am I correct assuming we're talking about an Excel solution? (i.e., not google-sheet, or a programming-language solution)? Please edit your question to reflect that. Welcome and good luck!

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear. This is an excel table. The table on the left is the log. The table on the right is the where i need the formulas. I need Column H to return the most recent Date, and Column I to return the most recent name of the person who performed the task.

Comment: Maybe try using a pivot table? I suggest you try seeing if a pivot table can be set to show only max(date) per person. If you're unfamiliar with pivot tables, take a look regardless of the answer to this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into pivot tables?